# Failed to save changes with EF DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am learning EF Code First from "Programming Entity Framework Code First". The following code snippets are copied from page 5 to page 7.

### Visit.cs

```
using System;

namespace ChapterOne
{
    class Visit
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public String ReasonForVisit { get; set; }
        public String Outcome { get; set; }
        public Decimal Weight { get; set; }
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### AnimalType.cs

```
namespace ChapterOne
{
    class AnimalType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Patient.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ChapterOne
{
    class Patient
    {
        public Patient()
        {
            Visits = new List<Visit>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public AnimalType AnimalType { get; set; }
        public DateTime FirstVisit { get; set; }
        public List<Visit> Visits { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### VetContext.cs

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ChapterOne
{
    class VetContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Visit> Visits { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ChapterOne
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dog = new AnimalType { TypeName = "Dog" };

            var patient = new Patient
            {
                Name = "Simpson",
                BirthDate = new DateTime(2008, 1, 28),
                AnimalType = dog,
                Visits = new List<Visit> 
                { 
                    new Visit 
                    { 
                        Date = new DateTime(2011, 9, 1)
                    }
                }

            };

            using (var context = new VetContext())
            {
                context.Patients.Add(patient);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error. Could you tell me what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: This message tells us "Something's gone wrong. Look into the `InnerException` if you want to know what exactly". You can do that if you click on the "View Detail" link in the exception message. Without that info nobody here will be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're not filling all required fields. The one i noticed is `Patient.FirstVisit` default value is not acceptable by sql server.

Comment: I don't have much experience with SqlServer, but I figured it would insert `DateTime.MinValue` if unspecified. Does that not happen with SqlServer?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the cause of your exact error, but will probably cause another error too; Your `VetContext` should contain 1 more line:

```
public DbSet<AnimalType> AnimalTypes { get; set; }
```

Otherwise, EF won't make an `AnimalType` table in the DB to insert the

```
var dog = new AnimalType { TypeName = "Dog" };
```

record into.